websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 401
I am trying to connect to websocket with the given code below.
import asyncio
import websockets
import ssl

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect('wss://...',
                                  ssl=ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)) as websocket:
        data = 'hi'
        await websocket.send(data)
        print("> {}".format(data))

        response = await websocket.recv()
        print("< {}".format(response))

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())

However, I am getting this error message:
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 401

Here is my alternative code:
import asyncio
import websocket
import rel

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://...",
                            on_open=on_open,
                            on_message=on_message,
                            on_error=on_error,
                            on_close=on_close,
                            header={'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
                                                  'Origin': 'https://challenge.longshotsystems.co.uk'})

ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)

Which gives me this message:
Handshake status 401 Unauthorized -+-+- {'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'date': 'Thu, 20 Jun 2024 06:33:03 GMT', 'content-length': '18'} -+-+- b'Session not found\n'
### closed ###

